# Linking MTL (Matrix Template Library) in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have MTL header files; I want to use those header files in Visual Studio 2008. How can I link those header files so that I can write a matrix program using the MTL library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're referring to how to tell the IDE to notice them? In that case, you can simply add them in a directory to your project. In VS, right-click the project, select Properties. Go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General. Add the MTL directory, and any sub-directory, to the Additional Include Directories field.

Comment: Thanks Loan for your reply, can you tell me how to include library (.lib file) in our project..

Comment: Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General. Add the directory/directories of the library files to the Additional Library Directories field. Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input. Add the .lib files to the Additional Dependencies field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link header files. You need to simply **include** them along with your sources.